# QtMediaPlayer issue

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am working with PyQt5 and trying to play a video on my Python application.

I am using Python 3.4.0 and PyQt 5.2.1 and running the application on Ubuntu 14.04, but it 
id important to make codes cross-platform.

When I run these codes, I get the error of

`defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"`

My codes:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import PyQt5.QtMultimedia as M
class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("IKA Control Panel")
        url= QUrl.fromLocalFile("./some.mp3")
        content= M.QMediaContent(url)
        self.player = M.QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.play()
        self.player.stateChanged.connect( app.quit )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    screen = Form()
    screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As well as OS, you also need to state which versions of Qt and PyQt5 you are using. Also, the example code is broken, because the media-player will get garbage-collected before it gets a chance to play anything - you need to keep a reference to it (i.e. `self.player = M.QMediaPlayer(self)`, etc).

Comment: @ekhumoro I edited the question in the way which answers your questions, and edited the code as you said.

Comment: @KeremZaman. You didn't give the Qt version, which is probably the most important one. Have there been recent ubuntu upgrades for Qt recently? Do you have all the necessary multimedia plugins installed (e.g. gstreamer-ffmpeg, libqt5multimedia, etc)?

Comment: @ekhumoro Qt version is the same as PyQt, so I didn't need to give. Also, I don't know which plugins and updates that I need to install even I searched a lot.

Comment: @KeremZaman. Do you want help or not? PyQt versions don't always match up with Qt versions, so you did need to give it. And I've just told you what plugins you need to have installed.

Comment: @ekhumoro Sorry, you are right. I've installed gstreamer-ffmpeg like here: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/get-firefox-and-phonon-gstreamer-to.html and libqt5multimedia5-dbg (libqt5multimediawidgets5 and libqt5multimedia5 is already installed) But there is still the same problem.

Comment: @KeremZaman. Do you have all the other gstreamer-0.10 packages installed (libgstreamer, gstreamer-plugins-*, etc)?

Comment: @ekhumoro I have installed packages in the way that described here: http://askubuntu.com/a/520986 But it didn't affect unfortunately.

Comment: @KeremZaman. I think this is clearly a distro-specific problem, rather than a programming problem, so it would be better to ask on one of the ubuntu forums instead.

Answer (score 2):

Install Qt5 plugins if you are using Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins
```